# Can you statically route to a subnet-conflicting (but not IP-conflicting) device on WAN side of a router?

Tags: networking, routing, subnet

As the title suggests, I have a weird question. We had an ISP technician at a customer's home install a router in front of our own router and misconfigured it. The ISP router is now in front of ours and is on the same subnet as our router's LAN. I would prefer not to visit the site directly (though I will if I have to.)

Additional background:

### Current network setup

- Internet <-> (WAN: irrelevant) ISP Router (LAN: 192.168.1.1/24) <-> (WAN: 192.168.1.50) Our router (LAN: 192.168.1.2/24) <-> rest of 192.168.1.0/24
- By sheer dumb luck, we have no IP conflicts due to how we have our DHCP pool configured on our router, so the site currently has outside network access

**Would it be possible for me to configure static routes on our router to be able to connect to the ISP router using a management device I currently have on the network?** Essentially, I want to add static routes to our router so that a small SSH device I have on the internal-most L2 can route to the ISP router and configure it so that its off the subnet and won't cause further issues.

I hope it doesn't sound too weird or dumb, and I thank anyone willing to help, even if it's just a matter of saying "no, you dummy, you can't do that."

Comment: Routers route packets between networks, not from a network back to the same network, so router interfaces need to be in different networks.

Comment: This was exactly what I was afraid of. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Yes, you can. The main problem here is that ISP router should have a route behind yours. You have to split networks first, 192.168.1.0/25 on WAN and 192.168.1.128/25 on LAN of your router. Then you either configure NAT on your router or make it use arp proxy what is Cisco default.
You may not touch LAN segment with mgmt device, but they both should have route to 1.1 through your router.

Comment: @kab00m, subnetting a network like that is creating separate networks, something the OP wished to avoid.

Comment: This might work with static routes too, because adding /32 route is exactly the same splitting. If static /32 route will be added on mgmt device and on the router - it will be always selected prior to more wide /24 interface route. Anyway he will need either NAT or arp proxy to get returning packet. This also depends on platform, but i was just checked Linux and BSD - /32 distant route win /24 interface route.